# Ellipsize textview at a specific word

Tags: android, textview

I need to ellipsize a possibly lengthy sentence at the desired word. For example in the sentence :

> Hello Stephen Hawking, how are you doing ?

Stephen Hawking is a dynamic text, which can be arbitrarily long. I would like to truncate that word and not others :

> Hello Ste..., how are you doing ?

[Android TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.TruncateAt.html) offer an enum for truncating, but I don't see my issue resolved with either. Can there be another way ? I just know the position of the word to be truncated.

Comment: why wouldn't you use two textviews

Comment: dynamic text, you mean with this i come from variable in your code or what ?

Comment: Dynamic text meaning, I don't know the word in advance. It comes from backend server.

Comment: @user2450263 : I was avoiding another textview because I was afraid what if both the first and second textviews are ellipsized in certain edge cases. I can't go for singleLine mode for both in that case. But seems like this is the only way to go. You can write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two textviews would provide a simple and effective solution in this case.

1 for the "Hello NameHere" and the 2nd one for the rest of the text.

Can specify the required ellipsize for the first one.
Optimal with the least overheads for the required output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this tested working solution

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView txtView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtView.setText("Hello Stephen Hawking, how are you doing ?Are you fine dude?");
        doEllipsize(txtView, "Stephen Hawking");
    }

    public void doEllipsize(final TextView tv, final String word) {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                if(tv.getLineCount()>1){
                    String replacedString = tv.getText().toString().replace(word, word.substring(0, 3)+"...");
                    tv.setText(replacedString);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this would ellipsize the sentence everytime. I need ellipsis only when the text is long enough not to fit in a single line (which is again device dependent). This is how Android ellipsize works...

Answer (score 0):

This code is use full for you..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Stephen Hawking" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:text=", " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="how are you doing ?" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on user2450263's accepted answer here is an example.
As my comment indicates below I used the layout_weight attribute to force the LinearLayout to measure twice. Without that part the word on the right would be pushed off the screen if the main text is ellipsized.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Using a weight to force the LL to measure twice  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suffix"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If that doesn't work for you or if you need to do this in a bunch of different places you can also create a custom widget.

---

Here's how you'd do that.
Custom view:

```
public class EllipsizedTextViewWithSuffix extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView mainText, suffix;

    public EllipsizedTextViewWithSuffix(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public EllipsizedTextViewWithSuffix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public EllipsizedTextViewWithSuffix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.ellipsized_tv_with_suffix, this);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        suffix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suffix);
    }

    public void setText(String mainText, String suffix) {
        this.mainText.setText(mainText);
        this.suffix.setText(suffix);
    }
}
```

Layout file (**ellipsized_tv_with_suffix.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Using a weight to force the LL to measure twice  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suffix"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

And then to use it you'll just need to add it to another layout. 
Replace with the correct package name of course.

```
<your.package.name.EllipsizedTextViewWithSuffix
    android:id="@+id/ellipsized_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```